# Stylesheet is not loading in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have two routes

> '/test'

which return the memberProfile blade. It works fine. But the other one

> '/memberProfile/{id}'

which sends the request to memberController from where it returns the memberProfile blade. But this time the blade could not load the master layouts stylesheets. Instead of searching the stylesheets in path

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/

it search the css in a path like

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/memberProfile/css/

.
here is web.php

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('members.memberProfile');
});
Route::get('/memberProfile/{id}','memberController@memberProfile');
```

and memberController class

```
public function memberProfile(Request $request){
        $id = decrypt($request->id);
        $Member = Member::find($id);
        $Member->Research->all();
        $MemberProject = Member::find($id);
        $MemberProject->Project->all();
        $MemberPublication = Member::find($id);
        $MemberPublication->Publication->all();
        return view('members.memberProfile',['members' => $Member , 'memberProject' => $MemberProject , 'memberPublication' => $MemberPublication]);
    }
```

What is the problem

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, or at least post what you have tried so far (code)/what you're trying to do (be more specific). This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: I have found the problem instead of searching the stylesheets in app\public\css folder the route request is searching the stylesheets in another folder. how to solve it?

Comment: @lealceldeiro please check the latest question

Answer (score 0):

You've to add the base url when you add a css or javascript file in view files :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo URL::asset('assets/css/style.css'); ?>">


<script src="<?php echo URL::asset('assets/js/angular.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Those are added to the master blade layout. The stylesheets of master blade template are loading perfectly for another requests. But in the  given request the stylesheets are not loading. master template is being extended to every page

Comment: You must use like this in every page. Or you can load all stylesheets in Master blade.